# Turn range of numbers into a comma divided list (Classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

Seems like a really common question, but have yet to find a Classic ASP example.

I have data presented like the following from the database we have inherited:

120-128,10,20,30,12-19

I need to be able to convert this into a comma divided list, in consecutive order, pulling not only the numbers present, but the numbers within the ranges (specified by the -)

So in the above example, I would expect the output of:

10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,30,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128

THEN I want to be able to store that result as a single variable, so I can do more work with it later.

I have found Python Methods, C#, Javascript, PHP etc, but not one for Classic ASP.
Can anyone help?

FYI, there would never be any duplicate numbers, each number will be unique.

Comment: Could you post your Javascript solution.  In Classic ASP you can use JS as a server side language instead of VBS

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's quite a nice little interview question involving string manipulation, arrays, sorting and de-duplicating. Interested to see your JS code. As John says though, you may be able to run the JS on the server anyway so a pure ASP solution may not be required.

Comment: @John Classic ASP supports Active Scripting languages which includes JScript not JavaScript. When you specify JavaScript as the server-side language you are actually using JScript which is based on the ECMAScript 3 specification so don’t confuse that with modern JavaScript which is currently at least ECMAScript 6 and ECMAScript 2020 was released this year so it’s constantly evolving, unlike JScript which is ES3 and won’t change.

Comment: Good point on the JS vs JScript Lanky. Even JScript would have the base capabilities for achieving the OP's needs though ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Absolutely, just wanted to point out they should not be treated the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic steps to do this are

1. Split your initial list by commas
2. Iterate through each of those items, checking if there's a hyphen
3. If there's a hyphen, then loop from the start to end, and add that value to an array, if there is no hyphen, then just add the value

At that point you have a list of all values, unsorted, and not unique.

In Classic ASP, you can use an Arraylist to help with the sorting and uniqueness. Create two arraylist objects. One will contain the non-unique list, and then the other will contain your final unique list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<body>
    <p>
        <%

    v="120-128,10,20,30,12-19,13-22" 'our original string to parse

    set uniqueList=CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 'final unique list
    set mynumbers=CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")  'a working list

    'first split the values by the comma
    splitCom=Split(v, ",")

    'now go through each item
    for itemnumber=0 to ubound(splitCom)
        itemToAdd=splitCom(itemnumber)
       
        if InStr(itemToAdd, "-")>0 then  'if the item has a hyphen, then we have a range of numbers
            rangeSplit=Split(itemToAdd, "-")

            for itemToAdd=rangeSplit(0) to rangeSplit(1)
                mynumbers.Add CInt(itemToAdd)
            next
        else
            mynumbers.Add Cint(itemToAdd) 'otherwise add the value itself
        end if
    next

    'at this point, mynumbers contains a full list of all your values, unsorted, and non-unique.

    mynumbers.sort  'sort the list. Can't be any easier than this

    'output the non-unique list, and build a unique list while we are at it.
    Response.Write("Non-unique list<br />")

    for each item in mynumbers                      'iterate through each item
        Response.Write(item & "<br />")             'print it
            if (not uniqueList.Contains(item)) then 'is the value in our unique list?
                uniqueList.Add(item)                'no, so add it to the unique list
            end if
    next

    'now output the unique list.
    Response.Write("<br />Unique list<br />")
    for each item in uniqueList
        Response.Write(item & "<br />")
    next
        %>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```